# Control visual styles of individual gridlines

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, gridlines

I have a `c# RangeBar chart` with about 25 labels on the AxisX. Depending on my live data, some of these labels have visible data points in the chart. Typically about 3/4 of the 25 labels don't have any data points. All horizontal gridlines are enabled, which makes the chart a bit cluttered. Especially for data points that are further away on the AxisY, it's difficult to distinguish at a glance to what label on the AxisX they belong.

My idea is to differentiate the AxisX labels that have visible data points either by giving their gridline a different color, a different style, or to completely remove gridlines of AxisX labels that have no corresponding data points. Is this even possible? Because all controllable properties and documentation I have found so far is regarding gridline styles of the entire chart.

Btw: Only showing AxisX labels that have data points is not an option.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reduce clutter you could use the `axis.Interval` property.

But **each** line will still have the **same** style, either of major or of the minor lines.

You could add `VerticalLineAnnotations` for selected points or try `StripLines`. Both can be styled freely.

Here is an example of a normal line chart, with lines randomly added to a few points:
[image]

The same result can be achieved by either `Annotations` or `Striplines`. The blue lines are `StripLine` and the red ones `Annotations`. Here are two functions to add a colored line to a `DataPoint`:

```
void AddStripLine(Chart chart, ChartArea ca, DataPoint dp, Color col)
{
    Axis ax = ca.AxisX;
    StripLine sl = new StripLine();
    sl.BorderColor = col;
    sl.IntervalOffset = dp.XValue;
    sl.Interval = 0;
    sl.StripWidth  = 0;
    sl.BorderWidth  = 1;
    ax.StripLines.Add(sl);
}
```

If you look very closely you'll see that the only visual difference is that the former are below, the latter above all other chart elements.

```
void AddAnnotation(Chart chart, ChartArea ca, DataPoint dp, Color col)
{
    Axis ay = ca.AxisY;
    VerticalLineAnnotation vl = new VerticalLineAnnotation();
    vl.LineColor = col;
    vl.AnchorDataPoint = dp;
    vl.IsInfinitive = true;
    vl.LineWidth = 1;
    vl.Height = ay.Maximum - ay.Minimum;
    vl.ClipToChartArea = ca.Name;
    chart.Annotations.Add(vl);
}
```

For `Bar` charts use `HorizontalLineAnnotations` and anchor to the correct axis...

Using `Annotatons` is in fact the more natural way, since each is an individual object. `StripLines` are too, but are **repeated** at intervals . To avoid visible repetiton each needs to have suitable **offsets** and **intervals** to be determined for each. But it isn't hard to do either way.

Also note that the both types of lines lines are **anchored** to their `DataPoints` and will **move** with them e.g. when chart is resized..

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Did not implement your answer directly, but it did lead me to the following solution: For every label that has visible points, I add a HorizontalLineAnnotation (remember, I have a RangeBar charttype, so AxisX is horizontal) with Width = 1 and a so-far unused color. Changed the MajorGrid.LineColor to Color.LightGray. This created the intended effect of existing points standing out visually and also easier tracking of data points to labels!

Comment: this brings up a final minor issue. The `HorizontalLineAnnotation` (HLA) visually overlaps the datapoint. The datapoint has a Width of 10, whereas the hla has Width of 1, so information wise nothing is lost, but from a perspective of cleanliness I would like the datapoint to overlap the HLA instead. However none of the HLA's properties seem to be enabling anything in that direction, is this possible somehow?

Comment: Um, the best bet with Annotation is to use a semi-transparent color. StripLines are below all other elements, if that is necessary..

Comment: I have added an example for striplines.