# How to Add an Image to a Chart

Tags: c#, image, charts

[[image: Chart I currently Have[1]]

I have a Chart like this, It's not finished yet but I need to add this image to the left of the Chart.[image]

The chart is a Chart control from C# and the Second Image is a .png . 
How can I go about putting the image on the chart?
The Chart is made on a .aspx page and is returned as an Image to be shown on a report so I need to be able to Return the Chart with the image on it as an Image.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways..:

- You can add an  [ImageAnnotation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.imageannotation?view=netframework-4.7.2)..

In order to place it correctly you will need to know exactly what you want.

[image]

Here is the example code to produce the above image:

```
chart1.Images.Add(new NamedImage("gradient", Image.FromFile(yourImagePath)));
ImageAnnotation imgA = new ImageAnnotation();
imgA.Image = "gradient";
imgA.ImageWrapMode = ChartImageWrapMode.Scaled;

imgA.IsSizeAlwaysRelative = false;
imgA.AxisY = ay;

imgA.Y = ay.Minimum;
imgA.Height =  ay.Maximum - ay.Minimum;

imgA.X = 0;
imgA.Width = 3;

chart1.Annotations.Add(imgA);
```

Chart [coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37024717/chart-annotations-how-can-i-align-the-annotation-along-an-axis-of-a-datapoint/37039637?s=1|50.9509#37039637) are tricky.

Note that the `Height` and `Y` are in `axis value coordinates` since I have associated the Annotation with the Y-Axis as I also turned off `IsSizeAlwaysRelative`.

By default `Annotatons`  are in **relative coordinates**, ie percentages of the respective containers. The horizontal numbers still are relative, so the `3` means `3%` of the chart's width and the `X = 0` positions the `Annotation` at the left egde..

---

Second way:

- To place an image inside the plot area but below all gridlines and points you can use a [`StripLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.stripline?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead of the `Annotation`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53520897/control-visual-styles-of-individual-gridlines/53526986#53526986).

Example:

```
StripLine sl = new StripLine();
sl.IntervalOffset = -1;
sl.Interval = 0;
sl.StripWidth  = 0.33;
sl.BorderWidth  = 0;
sl.BackImage =  "gradient";
sl.BackImageWrapMode = ChartImageWrapMode.Scaled;
ax.StripLines.Add(sl);
```

[image]

Note that `StripLines` are in axis value coordinates!

The image should be added to the `Chart.Images` as a `NamedImage`.. When you do a `chart.SaveImage`  the annotation or the stripline will be included..